# Error Cannot register assembly ClassA.Dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-assembly, gac

I have 2 class libraries ClassA and ClassB. ClassB is referenced on ClassA. I built CliassA take the dll from the bin register it on the gac using the gacutil.exe and everything runs fine. Now I have some changes to ClassA so I make the changes any try to built the ClassA again I get the compiler error.

Error Cannot register assembly ClassA.Dll. Could not load file or assembly 'ClassB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="" or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Both the class libraries are stronglyNamed with different .snk 
Both Lib have com visible true
Both are on .net 4.5 c#

Things I tried and didn't work:

- Unregister the ClassA from the Gac using gacutil.exe /u
- Unload both Libraries reload and re built.
- Restart VS, run it under Admin.
- Restart System.

The only thing tht works is to create a new Class Library ClassC, copy over the code from ClassA to ClassC and remove ClassA. then I can built it but only one time ..If I try to rebuilt it again the same error.

I can continue doing this copy paste for every single line of code change.

I tried to look for something tht was conceptually wrong with wat I am doing but was unable to figure out.

Surely Version issue but no clue on how to resolve this..Already wasted a day on this, any info will be of great help at this point.

Comment: `I built CliassA take the dll from the bin register ` what do you mean? Are you building `ClassA`, adding it to GAC and reference it from there?

Comment: @Kamo Yes I need to use this dll in other projects